# Is it possible for a cargo feature to remove a dependency?

Tags: rust, dependency-management, rust-cargo, rust-no-std

I am looking to add the possibility to add the possibility of using my crate without the standard library. Some of the core functionality does depend on floating-point functions, which in no-std mode would need to be provided by libm.

The usual way I've seen no-std setup is to have a feature called "std" that enables the standard library, but in this case I would want the feature to remove the libm dependency. I could call the "additional" feature "no-std", but that then leads to the issue that I have certain features that would be difficult to implement in no-std mode, so I'd want them to depend on std being enabled.

Is it possible for cargo to specify an optional dependency that is present only when a feature is not enabled?

Comment: Aaah sorry I misread the problem. Then I don't think it's possible and the only thing you can do is create two features (one for libm and one for std) and use conditional to trigger a compilation error if neither or both is enabled. [possibly related issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2980)

Answer (score 2):

No, Cargo features cannot remove dependencies.

Dependencies can be specified with `optional = true` which are not included unless enabled via a feature, but the mechanism cannot disable a dependency. See [optional dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#optional-dependencies) in the Cargo Book for how that works. Cargo features are generally designed to be additive and thus adding one should not generally remove functionality.

Your use-case is a bit out of the norm so your best route is to follow what @Masklinn suggested and create "mutually exclusive" features (not officially supported):

- have a `"std"` and `"libm"` features such that the `"libm"` feature enables the libm dependency

  ```toml
  [features]
  default = ["std"]
  std = []
  libm = ["dep:libm"]

  [dependencies]
  libm = { version = "*", optional = true }
  ```
- trigger a compiler error if both are enabled:

  ```rust
  #[cfg(all(feature = "std", feature = "libm"))]
  compile_error!("features \"std\" and \"libm\" cannot be enabled simultaneously")
  ```

Still not ideal since, again, Cargo features are generally designed to be additive and due to feature-unification both may be enabled unintentionally but at least the above compiler error message should help.